# How can I get GitLab CI/CD jobs to push to external repositories?

Tags: python, git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I've been having issues getting Gitlab CI/CD to push new changes to the current repository. Apparently, this can not be done as of now. So now, I am attempting to see if it can push to other repositories.

This is what I'm trying to do:

- Clone another repo into mine

  - let's call mine **Router**)
  - let's call the other **Rinner**)
- Modify **Rinner** in some way
- Commit and Push only the changes to **Rinner**
- Then remove **Rinner** from **Router**

I'm trying to test this out in Python, and currently have this:

```
    os.system('mkdir temp');
    os.chdir('temp');
    os.system('git clone git@gitlab.com/path/Rinner.git');
    os.chdir('Rinner');
    os.system('echo "Hello World!" > hello.txt');
    os.system('git add -A');
    os.system('git commit -m "Running a test..."');
    os.system('git push --force');
    os.chdir('..');
    os.chdir('..');
    os.system('rm -rf temp');
```

On my local machine, it works perfect fine.

On my GitLab CI/CD job, I get the following result.

```
Cloning into 'Rinner'...
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

How can I go about getting past this when it operates on GitLab CI/CD?

Comment: Looking at your Python code: have you considered using a shell script instead of wrapping shell commands in Python?

Comment: Are you using a shared runner or a runner in a cloud, or is your runner also your local machine?

Comment: @svdragster It's just a shared runner within my GitLab project. I normally use it for running schedule jobs, but I'm trying to test this out first.

Comment: Then I'd guess the runner probably isn't authenticated or allowed to access the other repository.

Comment: @KlausD. Yes, but I didn't plan to do that just yet. I wanted to make sure I had something working first.

Comment: Does it matter at all that I created both of the repositories?

Comment: The message "Host key verification failed." indicates a host key verification issue. You might have to clean the old key(s) from `~/.ssh/known_hosts` on the runner.

Answer (score 0):

You are cloning `git clone git@gitlab.com/path/Rinner.git` over SSH and problem is that You have wrong fingerprint of server stored on your runner in ~/.ssh/known_hosts

You can try also `ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null git@gitlab.com` vs `ssh git@gitlab.com`. You will se a difference.

You need to remove this fingerprint or disable StrictHostKeyChecking